# Best Way of Generating Random Domain Names

Tags: python, url, random, combinations

I need to make some request to as much websites as I could, so I have a small function that generates random domain names, (I need them as 'brute force' for making requests to this domains), this is my function:

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase

def _create_domain(self):
    return [''.join(i) for i in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat = 5)]
```

This function returns an array of all posible 5-letter combinations, and then I use that random words to create an url.
Actually the majority of this 'words' isn't real domain names `['aaaaa', 'aaaab' ....]` so it's a huge waste of time make requests to all this words, but I can't think of a better way of doing this, do you think there's a more optimal way?

Comment: Why are you making requests to random domain names? Sounds spammy.

Comment: Hahaha, it sound like that but I'm actually working on some algorithm, and instead of manually adding some domain names to make the requests, I thought that creating a function instead'll be much more interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this by scraping a web directory and building four or five data frames with keywords. So data frame one might be sport, climb, ball, active, and data frame two would be red, blue, sky, etc that might generate more probable websites. Otherwise, if you are set on the pure brute force I think you can only upgrade your computer.